# Missing header files. Is wxWidgets incomplete/outdated?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I got a project to develop a native Windows application that will be cross-platform later. They told me to work with wxWidgets but I have been having trouble finding good clear information besides the class reference files they provide.

I am trying to use components from the GUI Builder and for example when I insert a wx/stateLed it gives me an error saying that the wx/stateLed.h file can't be found.

I checked the installation folder and there is nothing. I had that problem with other components but I imported the header files. This along other components I need don't seem to be available.

Is wxWidgets incomplete/outdated?

Comment: In a separate directory, download and install the sources for the version you are using.  Check your wxWidget header directory against the sources you downloaded.  Also, verify that you have installed all the features you need.

Comment: @Galvar, what type of IDE/GUI Builder do you use? What version of wxWidgets you have? Are you using native C++ library or python binding/Phoenix project? Also - what is "stateLed"? There is no such control in the library?.

Comment: @Galvar, in addition - just installing the library is not enough. You need to actually build it using a compiler of your choice - MSVC or MinGW (whatever is available).

Comment: Hi guys thank you for the input, I am using Code::Blocks. I built the library using Cmake and it fixed a lot of the issues.

Comment: I had no idea about the contributed plugins I really appreciate that, it is gonna save some time of headaches figuring it out. Thanks again for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

wxWidgets is actively maintained. You can trust on it.

I found **stateLed.h** inside Code::Blocks contributed pluggins. It means this is not a control you can add to your own app.

BUT, there are `wxLed` and `wxLEDPanel` and `LCDWindow` controls. These are not part of the official wxWidgets sources. They are contributed code that can be found at [wxCode components](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/complist.php).

Download the one you wish and tell your IDE (C::B ?) where to find them

Comment: @Rip2, I guess without more info (which IDE is being used) we can't provide more info....